# Netbeans 8.1 uninstall.sh corrupted on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: netbeans, software-uninstall, screen-corruption

Before this happened... I located `uninstall.sh` file and when I opened it.. it said some characters are undefined *something of that sort* and asked 'do you want to save it anyway' and I accidentally clicked yes after which it showed this

[image: image...]

How am I suppose to resolve and uninstall netbeans 8.1 or in that case reinstall it on Ubuntu

Comment: Please do not write in caps lock

Comment: Please paste terminal output as text, not [screenshots](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals).

Comment: We want the error message not a poetic description of what the error message might be similar to

Answer (score 0):

For Complete removal of Netbeans 8.1 execute the file uninstall.sh. It will be in the location /usr/local/netbeans8.1/

```
sudo ./uninstall.sh
```

else try the following:

```
$ bash ~/netbeans-7.2.1/uninstall.sh
```

I hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall NetBeans 8.1 in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo sh /usr/local/netbeans-8.1/uninstall.sh
```

NetBeans 8.1 can be installed in Ubuntu 16.04 from the default Ubuntu repositories. NetBeans 8 targets Java 8 as its compatible Java version. To reinstall NetBeans 8.1 in Ubuntu 16.04, Java 8 (openjdk-8-jdk) from the default Ubuntu repositories should be the version of Java referenced by `java -version` and run this command:

```
sudo apt install netbeans
```